# How to pull day of month from Column header including row data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Calendar look]

Trying to make a report where employee needs to work 30 working days since last point. I would like to have someway to show anything with 8.0 as working day. So column std_01_04 would show as 12/04/2020 and as a work day.

The sql database has been set up very goofy and having issues pulling from it.

- there is a column named yr, data shows the current year "2020"
- there is a column named mth_cal, show current month "12" for December.

The tricky part is the day. Column is std_01_15 the last 2 numbers are day of month, this example is the 15th. The data under that column will be a 0 or 8. 8 means they worked(full day) or 0 which means day off/holiday. So I need to pull data from a few spots to make a date and need to figure out 30 working days since last point. Any help would be great.

Edit: This was designed by different company. I have no way of redesigning this. I can only try to work with it. Or I need to go with manually entering all holidays/days off

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What a mess. Dynamic SQL can help you, but it will be some work.

Comment: Seems like fixing the design is what you *really* need to do.

Comment: It might be helpful to unpivot the data to get the dates and hours worked into rows, to address some of the design issues.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create store procedure or function with input param @year and @month with code below to get all day with 8.0 working hours.

```
declare @year int = 2020
declare @month int = 11

create table #temp (workingDay date)

declare @index int = 1
declare @query nvarchar(200)
declare @paramdef nvarchar(300) = '@valOut nvarchar(10) OUTPUT'
declare @value nvarchar(10)

while @index <= 30
begin
    set @query = 'select @valOut = STD_01_'+ REPLACE(STR(@index, 2), SPACE(1), '0')  +' from work where yr='+ CAST(@year as nvarchar(4));  
    exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @valOut = @value output

    if @value = '8.0'
    begin
        insert into #temp values(CAST(@year as nvarchar(4)) + REPLACE(STR(@month + 1, 2), SPACE(1), '0') + REPLACE(STR(@index, 2), SPACE(1), '0'))
    end

    set @index = @index + 1
end

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

This is result when i run this code in SQL Server
[image]

Comment: Thats works amazing thank you! I just need to figure out how to enter date and see how many days past that. Example. 30 working days after 11-25-2020 is what day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you require results like below. You can use `unpivot` in sql server.

[image: Test]

I have tested with below query.

```
    Create table TestUnpivot(yr int , mnth int, std_01_01 int, std_01_02 int, std_01_03 int, primary key(yr,mnth) )
go

Insert into TestUnpivot values(2019,12,0,8,8),(2020,1,8,0,8),(2020,2,8,8,8)
go

Select * from TestUnpivot
go
Select Yr,Mnth, workd, dayss, Convert(Varchar(2),Mnth)+'/'+right(dayss,2)+'/'+convert(Varchar(4),Yr) as DT
from
(
select * from TestUnpivot
)p
unpivot
(
workd for dayss in (std_01_01,std_01_02,std_01_03)
) as unp
go
```